# How do I convert my XNA game to Android without using MonoGame?

Tags: xna, android, xna-4.0, monogame

I want to convert my XNA Game to Android, but I don't want to use MonoGame or ExEn. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use monogame or ExEn?

Comment: All other options will require much more manual work and dealing with worth languages.

Answer (score 7):

There are no conversions of XNA to the android platform without using either MonoGame or EXNA. You will need to rewrite your game including all the rendering logic in either C# using Xamarin.Android or a complete rewrite in Java.